# What are Source-Level Statements?

Tags: computer-science

What are "source-level statements"?

"Algorithm determines both the number of source-level statements and the number of I/O operations executed" from Computer Organization and Design

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Statement*: A line of code which does something. Source-level means *in source code*, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever is called a "statement" by your high-level programming language.  Often a source-level statement translates (during compilation) to dozens of machine instructions.

For example, a statement may include a function call, which translates to not only a call instruction, but computation of the arguments, stack-manipulation instructions to push and pop the arguments before and after the call (depending on calling convention).  But it would only count as one "source-level" statement.